# Automatically restart Kubernetes Job after node shutdown

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-jobs

We are running a daily cronjob on GKE. This job is executed on spot nodes. The container respects the `SIGTERM` and gracefully shuts down. However, this is then marked as successful and not restarted. How can I ensure that this job is restarted on a different node?

I've read https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/nodes/#graceful-node-shutdown and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/#handling-pod-and-container-failures, but I see nothing in there that helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default the cron jobs in kubernetes are not rescheduled after a node shutdown. However you can configure the job to use a `restartPolicy` of `OnFailure` to ensure that it is rescheduled after a node shutdown.

You need to mention the restartPolicy in spec sections as follows

```
apiVersion: batch/v1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
 name: myjob
spec:
 schedule: "* * * * *"
 jobTemplate:
  spec:
   template:
    spec:
     containers:
       - name: myjob
         image: nginx
         imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
     restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

By using this **restartPolicy**, if a node is shutdown or the pod running the cron job terminates for any reason, the kubernetes scheduler will automatically reschedule the cronjob to run a healthy node.

**Note:** It is important to ensure that the cronjob required resources are available in the node.

Comment: Thanks! I can't edit your post (too few changes), but onFailure should be OnFailure.